# Model changed, but fields of collection in mongodb didn't

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails.js to create a web application. First, I created a model named Message which included fields:

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    content: 'string',
    sendTime: 'datetime'
  }
};
```

Then, I inserted some documents into the collection of mongodb. However, I wanted to modify the Message model, and now it looks like:

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    myId: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    content: 'string'
  }
};
```

When `sails lift` I chose `migrate:"drop"` . But I found that documents in mongodb remained the same fields after I inserted some new records. What did I do wrong? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What sails version and waterline adapter are you using?